# I'm trying to load my class o1 only on #post that does not already have a class o1. jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load my class o1 only on #post that does not already have a class o1.

http://jsfiddle.net/tx6gey3n/2/

```
    <div id="container">
     <div id="post">
      <div class="o1>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    $("#post").css('background-color', 'red');
    function addOverlays() {     
     var theDiv='<div class="o1"><div class="o2"></div></div>';
     jQuery(this).not( document.getElementsByClass( "o1" ) ).append(theDiv); 
     }
    addOverlays();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
$('#post').find('div').not('.o1').addClass('o1');
```

If you are just trying to add the class `.o1` to everything you can just use your selector to do that:

```
$('div').addClass('o1');
```

Comment: I get that jQuery is undefined... from your code. I have the other code but it repeats I need to make sure that the class is not already in existence before it adds it again

Comment: updated my code. jQuery will check if the class exists and it won't double add it.